# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Tried to use PaginationNotifier after `dispose` was called

Tags: flutter, state, riverpod

I have a StateNotifierProvider that calls an async function which loads some images from the internal storage and adds them to the AsyncValue data:

```
//Provider declaration
final paginationImagesProvider = StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<PaginationNotifier, AsyncValue<List<Uint8List?>>>((ref) {
  return PaginationNotifier(folderId: ref.watch(localStorageSelectedFolderProvider), itemsPerBatch: 100, ref: ref);
});

//Actual class with AsyncValue as State
class PaginationNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<List<Uint8List?>>> {
  final int itemsPerBatch;
  final String folderId;
  final Ref ref;
  int _numberOfItemsInFolder = 0;
  bool _alreadyFetching = false;
  bool _hasMoreItems = true;

  PaginationNotifier({required this.itemsPerBatch, required this.folderId, required this.ref}) : super(const AsyncValue.loading()) {
    log("PaginationNotifier created with folderId: $folderId, itemsPerBatch: $itemsPerBatch");
    init();
  }

  final List<Uint8List?> _items = [];

  void init() {
    if (_items.isEmpty) {
      log("fetchingFirstBatch");
      _fetchFirstBatch();
    }
  }

  Future<List<Uint8List?>> _fetchNextItems() async {
    List<AssetEntity> images = (await (await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList())
        .firstWhere((element) => element.id == folderId)
        .getAssetListRange(start: _items.length, end: _items.length + itemsPerBatch));
    List<Uint8List?> newItems = [];
    for (AssetEntity image in images) {
      newItems.add(await image.thumbnailData);
    }
    return newItems;
  }

  void _updateData(List<Uint8List?> result) {
    if (result.isEmpty) {
      state = AsyncValue.data(_items);
    } else {
      state = AsyncValue.data(_items..addAll(result));
    }
    _hasMoreItems = _numberOfItemsInFolder > _items.length;
  }

  Future<void> _fetchFirstBatch() async {
    try {
      _numberOfItemsInFolder = await (await PhotoManager.getAssetPathList()).firstWhere((element) => element.id == folderId).assetCountAsync;
      state = const AsyncValue.loading();
      final List<Uint8List?> result = await _fetchNextItems();
      _updateData(result);
    } catch (e, stk) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e, stk);
    }
  }

  Future<void> fetchNextBatch() async {
    if (_alreadyFetching || !_hasMoreItems) return;
    _alreadyFetching = true;

    log("data updated");
    state = AsyncValue.data(_items);

    try {
      final result = await _fetchNextItems();
      _updateData(result);
    } catch (e, stk) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e, stk);
      log("error catched");
    }

    _alreadyFetching = false;
  }
}
```

Then I use a scroll controller attached to a CustomScrollView in order to call fetchNextBatch() when the scroll position changes:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    if (!controller.hasListeners && !controller.hasClients) {
      log("listener added");

      controller.addListener(() {
        double maxScroll = controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
        double position = controller.position.pixels;

        if ((position > maxScroll * 0.2 || position == 0) && ref.read(paginationImagesProvider.notifier).mounted) {
          ref.read(paginationImagesProvider.notifier).fetchNextBatch();
        }
      });
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

The problem is that when the StateNotifierProvider is fetching more data in the async function fetchNextBatch() and I go back on the navigator (like navigator.pop()), Flutter gives me an error:

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Tried to use PaginationNotifier after `dispose` was called.
Consider checking `mounted`.

I think that the async function responsible of loading data completes after I've popped the page from the Stack (which triggers a Provider dispose).

I'm probably missing something and I still haven't found a fix for this error, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the state object is currently in a tree by using mounted in _updateData.

```
void _updateData(List<Uint8List?> result) {
  if (!mounted) {
    return;
  }

  if (result.isEmpty) {
    state = AsyncValue.data(_items);
  } else {
    state = AsyncValue.data(_items..addAll(result));
  }
  _hasMoreItems = _numberOfItemsInFolder > _items.length;
}
```